# NameError - uninitialized constant error in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, require

I have the following code in my "ProgramsController.rb " file where, Im using a class called "DataTableDelegate" which is in a separate file called: "datatable_delegate.rb"

```
 # GET /programs
 # GET /programs.json
 def index
    puts "Running Program/index"
puts "Model name = #{controller_name.classify}"
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
@datatable_options = generate_datatable_hash(view_context, controller_name.classify, Program.data_table_attribute_array )
log_with_blue("============================================")
log_with_yellow("#{@datatable_options.inspect}")
log_with_blue("============================================")
>>>>>> format.json { render json: DataTableDelegate.new( @datatable_options)  }
   end
   end
```

The file "datatable_delegate.rb" is located at

```
 app/datatables/datatable_delegate.rb
```

When I load the Programs url in the browser I get the following in my log:

Completed 500  in 237ms

```
 NameError - uninitialized constant ProgramsController::DataTableDelegate:
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:500:in `load_missing_constant'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
 app/controllers/programs_controller.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in index'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:191:in `respond_to'
 app/controllers/programs_controller.rb:13:in `index'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
 ......
```

I tried to put a require statement in my programs controller file but I still am getting the error.....

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your file to 'data_table_delegate.rb'. Also check whether the path `app/datatables` is in your `autoload_paths`.

Comment: I believe every sub directory under app/ is autoloaded .

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `require` statement in your `ProgramsController` as all files in the `app/` directory are autoloaded by Rails.

The problem is the way you're accessing the `DataTableDelegate`.  It is namespaced with `Datatable`, hence the placement of this file is in `app/datatables/` directory.

Try with the following:

```
::Datatable::DatatableDelegate.new( @datatable_options)
```

Please note the case of characters in the module and class names above.